# How to run jenkins job only once but with two conditions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Thanks for looking into my concern.

I have 3 jenkins jobs. JOb A, B & C.

1. Job A starts at 10PM at night.
2. JOB B is a down stream of Job A and runs only if job A is success.
3. Job C is a downstream job of job B

Now I want job C to be triggered after successful completion of job B or at at a scheduled time. Problem is if I schedule job C as down stream as well as with a schedule. It runs twice.
But, it should run only once.

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Please show some code showing what you have tried.

Comment: This is not related to any code. It's plugin based and I am looking for ideas to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "Conditional BuildStep" plug-in? You can execute a downstream job (or a script) based on "Build cause"

[image]

You can add more than 1 "single" conditions for each build cause.

Now you'll need to decide when to run a job, as a timer or as a downstream

Comment: in both of these cases, my downstream job runs twice, which I don't want to.
1. If upstream job is successful my downstream job runs and again due to timer it runs. There should be some OR condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jenkins [pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin). You can create a pipeline job with stages. A pipeline will proceed only to next stage if previous stage is successful. Refer documentation for more details on [pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/).

Pipeline comes with a lot of flexibilities in which you can define the flow. You can either use a declarative pipeline or a scripted pipeline. Good number of examples can be found in [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples)